# Highlighting search words like Chrome with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently done a very simple highlighting with jQuery and a highlight plugin. It looks like this:

> $('myButton').click(function() {
>
> $('body').highlight($('#myInputText').val());
>
> });

But I wonder how can I do the Chrome like highlighting, I mean highlight the letters whenever I type in some letter in textbox without submitting. I think maybe use a keyup event... Any ideas?

**Thanks Andy, i changed 'this[0]' to 'search[i]' in your code and it works if there is only one 'p' tag**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var search = ['p', 'div', 'span'];

  $("#highlighter").bind('keyup', function(e){
    var pattern = $(this).val();

    $.each(search, function(i){
        var str = search[i];        
        var orgText = $(str).text();

        orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
          return "<span style='background-color: red;'>" + $1 + "</span>"
        });

        $(str).html(orgText);
    });    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made quick excersise out of it, code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var search = ['p', 'div', 'span'];

    $("#highlighter").bind('keyup', function(e){
    var pattern = $(this).val();

    $.each(search, function(i){
        var str = this[0];        
        var orgText = $(str).text();

        orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
          return "<span style='background-color: red;'>" + $1 + "</span>"
        });

        $(str).html(orgText);
    });    
  });
});​​
```

link: http://jsbin.com/amica3/edit

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myInputText').keypress(function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13: // "Enter" was pressed; handle it if you want
            return false;

        case 27: // ESC was pressed; handle it if you want
            return false;
    }

    $('body').highlight($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've edited JAndy's code so the result would match all the occurences in the text and the search would not be case-sensitive.
[Link](http://www.jsbin.com/amica3/22/edit)
Hope someone finds this helpful