# Copying a webpage for later processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am completely new to Javascript. I am learning JavaSript and jQuery for my problem below.

So here's what I want to do:

1. I have a list of words ("foo", "bar")
2. Get the  current web page's content (html, css, content)
3. I want to re-render the page again but this time with "foo" and "bar" highlighted wherever they occur in the page.

I simply want to highlight  any page the user opens with a set of words that occur in the page.

As of now I am completely stuck step 1. Can someone please point me to an approach that I can read up on?

Comment: You can look up searching for a word in a `html` page using `js`, then add a tag `<span class="match">{word}</span>` to it and style your `.match` class with a specific background color

Comment: Questions asking to *recommend or find a... tutorial* are off-topic on StackOverflow.  Perhaps instead of looking for something so specific you should simply learn piece by piece.  How do I highlight text in CSS?  How do I replace text in JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlighting search words like Chrome with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551221/highlighting-search-words-like-chrome-with-jquery)

Comment: If you need to handle scraping with Javascript, I recommend Node with [Cheerio.](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Answer (score 1):

You can run this on a webpage to highlight text. For example, lets say the keyword we wanted to highlight was "completely":

```
var keyword = 'completely';
var items = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var element = items[i];
    if(element.innerHTML.split('<')[0].indexOf(keyword) > -1) {
       element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(keyword, '<span style="background-color: yellow">'+keyword+'</span>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll direct you to the right path. This snippet is not the best solution but it'll show you an example of how it can be done:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(match, '<span class="match">' + match + '</span>');
```

Then style `.match` class

**NOTE** `match` variable is the keyword you are looking to highlight

Answer (score 1):

you can grab the entire html of the page using

```
var text=document.body.innerHTML;
```

You could javascript for replacing every occurrence of word with below markup

```
"the sky is blue".replace(/sky/g,"<span class='highlight'>sky</span>");
```

Then you could add highlight class to your css file for styling.

You could refine your search for limiting it to only html text

Answer (score 0):

You can see an [example on JS Bin here.](http://jsbin.com/semolib/edit?html,js,output)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#highlighter").bind('keyup', function(e){
    var text = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(text !== '' && text !== ' '){
        var pattern = new RegExp(text, "gi");
    }
    $('p, div, span').each(function(i){
        var str = this;
        var orgText = $(str).text();
            orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
            return "<span style='background:red'>" + $1 + "</span>";
        });
        $(str).html(orgText); 
    });   
  });
});
```