# search function doesn't highlight multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, highlight

If I use this library(see below) for one text block then it works fine but I need it to work on multiple text blocks throughout my application. I have created a function which does this, however it seems to only highlight the first word entered into the search input or only the first character when this option[wholeWord: true] is set to false (although it logs all the data entered to the console). How could I edit my function to enable full functionality (highlighting all data entered)? Thank you in advance.

Library:

```
/**
 * highlight 1.0.0
 * Licensed under MIT
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2016 yjteam
 * http://yjteam.co.kr
 *
 * GitHub Repositories
 * https://github.com/yjseo29/highlight.js
 */

if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
  throw new Error("JavaScript requires jQuery");
}

+(function($) {
  "use strict";
  var version = $.fn.jquery.split(" ")[0].split(".");
  if (
    (version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) ||
    (version[0] == 1 && version[1] == 9 && version[2] < 1)
  ) {
    throw new Error("JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher");
  }
})(jQuery);

+(function($) {
  $.fn.highlight = function(word, options) {
    var option = $.extend(
      {
        background: "#ffff00",
        color: "#000",
        bold: false,
        class: "",
        ignoreCase: true,
        wholeWord: true
      },
      options
    );
    var findCnt = 0;

    if (this.length == 0) {
      throw new Error("Node was not found");
    }

    var $el = $('<span style="color:' + option.color + ';"></span>');
    if (option.bold) {
      $el.css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
    if (option.background != "") {
      $el.css("background", option.background);
    }
    if (option.class != "") {
      $el.addClass(option.class);
    }

    if (option.wholeWord) {
      word = "\\b" + escapeRegExp(word) + "\\b";
    }
    var re = new RegExp(word, option.ignoreCase == true ? "gi" : "g");

    this.each(function() {
      var content = $(this).html();

      $(this).html(
        content.replace(re, function(t) {
          findCnt++;
          $el.text(t);
          return $el.get(0).outerHTML;
        })
      );
    });
    return findCnt;

    function escapeRegExp(string) {
      return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Main.js

```
// highlight search terms in content
$("#searchInput").on("keyup change", function() {
  var option = {
    color: "#353535",
    background: "#fff",
    bold: false,
    ignoreCase: true,
    wholeWord: true
  };
  var searchVal = $("#searchInput").val();

  // console.log("value", searchVal);
  if (!searchVal || searchVal === "") {
    // console.log("no value", searchVal);
    // $("span").removeAttr("style");
    $(".searchtext").each(function() {
      $(this)
        .find("span")
        .contents()
        .unwrap();
      return;
    });
  } else {
    console.log("value", searchVal);
    $(".searchtext").each(function() {
      $(this).highlight(searchVal, option);
    });
  }
});
```

HTML:
Input:

```
<input id="searchInput" onkeyup="search()" class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search"><i type="reset" class="fas fa-search"></i></input>
```

Text block 1:

```
<p class="searchtext">first Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Text block two

```
<p class="searchtext">second Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jAndy . Found my answer here and scrapped the library: [Highlighting search words like Chrome with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551221/highlighting-search-words-like-chrome-with-jquery)

Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var search = ['p', 'div', 'span'];

    $("#highlighter").bind('keyup', function(e){
    var pattern = $(this).val();

    $.each(search, function(i){
        var str = this[0];        
        var orgText = $(str).text();

        orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
          return "<span style='background-color: red;'>" + $1 + "</span>"
        });

        $(str).html(orgText);
    });    
  });
});​​
```